# javascript no longer work after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am using this Image Picker jQuery plugin (http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) to select images in PicDiv to delete.

After select images I click DeleteButton to delete selected images by DeletePic.php and want to refresh PicDiv but after ajax request, javascript no longer work.

I have found the answer from other duplicate question that told me to binded event handlers but It still doesn't work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".image-picker").imagepicker({
            limit_reached: function () {
                alert('Limit is 5');
            }  
        });
        });
    $(document).on('click',"#DeleteButton",function(){
            /*get image path*/
            var req = $("div[class='thumbnail selected']").children('img');
            var imagessource = [];
            var srcc = [];
            $(req).each(function (datakey, datavalue) {
                src = $(datavalue).attr('src');
                imagessource.push(src);
            });

            /*delete and refresh*/
            var pp = $.post("DeletePic.php", { 
            'del[]': imagessource
            }, 
            function(){
                alert("OK");     
            }
            )
            .done(function(){
                $('#PicDiv').load(location.href + " #PicDiv");
            })
});    
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="PicDiv">
<?php

$arr = array();
$us = $_SESSION['Username'];
$i = 0;
mysql_connect("localhost", "AAAA", "AAAA");
mysql_select_db("test");

$strSQL = "SELECT path FROM tb_pic WHERE Username = '" . $us . "' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
?>
<select class="image-picker" multiple="multiple" data-limit="5">
    <?php
    while ($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
        ?>
        <option data-img-src="<?php echo $objResult['path']; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">AAAAAAAA</option>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
</div>

<input id="DeleteButton" name="Submit" type="button" value="Delete">
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with a class of "DeleteButton" on your page? Can you provide any relevant HTML?

Comment: can u just test a alert in click function

Comment: 1) `$("div[class='thumbnail selected']")` may not be a problem, but `$("div.thumbnail.selected")` is better. 2) `req` is already a `jQuery` object, so do not wrap again - `$(req)`. 3) Can `'del[]': imagessource` not be just `'del': imagessource`?

Comment: @LShetty I have edited as your advice but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @KJPrice quite sure. yes.

Comment: I see one with an ID="DeleteButton", but none with a class. Try "#DeleteButton" instead.

Comment: @JeremyThille thx I have edited somehow It still doesn't work.

Comment: What about `req.each` instead of `$(req).each`, as LShetty suggested? What does your console say - any errors? What if you log or alert stuff after `$(document).on('click'` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I have tested but nothing change. I still can get image path  as the old one but after ajax request,javascript still doesn't work

Comment: And what about my other questions?

Comment: @JeremyThille console doesn't say any error. alert is works fine after $(document).on('click')

Comment: Okay, try : `$req.each(function () {
                imagessource.push( $(this).attr('src') );
            });`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `$('#PicDiv').load(location.href + " #PicDiv")`; It looks like you're trying to load this very page into a div inside itself with a hash (???) Doesn't make much sense. Try commenting this out and test. It might break your script. And I'm starting to run out of ideas :)

Comment: $('#PicDiv') is div tag that display all images ,so I trying to automatically refresh this tag after I deleted selected images. :))